# Minimal cut of a directed graph such that disjoint elements are strongly connected

Tags: algorithms, graphs, connected-components, directed-graphs

Given an arbitrary directed graph $G$ (which may not necessarily be connected) find a minimum set of edges $S\subseteq E$ such that every disjoint component of $G(V,E\cap S')$ is strongly connected.

A "minimum set" refers to the set with the minimum number of edges. The best algorithm I could come up with is exponential, ex. iterating over all sets of edges. Could this be done faster or probabilistically?

Comment: Can you please clarify what "disjoint component of $G(V,S)$" is?

Comment: A subset of edges and nodes in G that are not connected to other subsets of edges and nodes in G by any edges

Comment: So are you talking about weakly connected components (i.e, convert the graph to be undirected, and then take the connected components in it)?

Comment: sorry, I was unclear, instead of "disjoint" in my original question, I should have used "disconnected" I mean to say that after cutting some number of edges, every disconnected component of the graph is strongly connected.

Comment: To be clear, no I do not mean weakly connected component.

Comment: Then please define "disconnected components" to make the question self-contained. I do not know of such a definition, so it will be helpful.

Comment: I use "disconnected" to mean having no edges between components, the same as used here [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fast algorithm for this problem: (assuming you meant that $S$ is the set of edges being *removed* from $G$)

1. Compute the strongly connected components of $G$, with an algorithm of your choice. For example, [this DFS-based algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strongly-connected-components/) can work in $O(|V|+|E|)$.
2. Define $S$ to be the set of edges between any two strongly connected components.

This algorithm is very efficient, running in linear time with respect to $|V|$ and $|E|$.

Additionally, it computes a correct set (which is easy to see why) and this set is the minimal set.

Indeed, if there is an edge $(v,u)$ that is between two strongly connected components, but it is not in $S$, then $(v,u)$ will be in the new graph. Notice there is no path $u\rightsquigarrow v$ (otherwise $v$ and $u$ would have been in the same strongly connected component) and hence, the new graph will contain a component that is not strongly connected.